# Hide/Unhide Canvas in Unity AR Project

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, canvas

I'm trying to hide/unhide a Canvas by scripting, i've already read the documentation to do so, but im not able to make it work (My Canvas has 3 buttons).

This is my code (I also tried without the lines `UI.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;` and `UI.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;`

Also tried with:

```
UI.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
```

And

```
UI.enabled = true;
```

Here's my code (Note: I have tried attaching this script in a GameObject, in the AR Main camera and nothing seems to work):

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 
 public class ShowHideCanvas : MonoBehaviour
 {
     public Canvas UI;
     public bool CanvasACtive;
     // Start is called before the first frame update
     void Start()
     {
         CanvasACtive = true;
     }
     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update()
     {
         if (CanvasACtive == true)
         {
             UI.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = true;
             UI.gameObject.SetActive(true);
             
         }
         else
         {
             UI.GetComponent<Canvas>().enabled = false;
             UI.gameObject.SetActive(false);
         }
     }
 }
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Diego.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm... I Copy your code and test it work with hide and unhide canvas.

Did you attach the script to canvas object ?
If you do, Remove it then attach the script to other gameobject instead of CanvasObject (becuase when you deactive gameobject update function will not call)

How you setup your component and hierarchy ?

Comment: Hi, did you try with in a Basic AR Scene? I created a new GameObject called "CanvasController" and i attach the script, then i drag and drop my Canvas Prefab in the UI variable, then i run the Scene and play around with the boolean "Active" button, and nothing happens. I also tried attaching the script to the AR Main Camera and same resulst.

Comment: Yes ... I want to know Canvas Prefab is on scene right (not in project folder) ? if yes what AR framework you used ?

Comment: I teid both, Prefab in the Scene and in the Porject, abbout the AR, just AR Foundation and ARCore

Comment: ACtually, you were right, i make it work with the Prefab in the Scene, and can you recommend the basics to learn or read to understand this behavior?

Comment: Very well. first thing you should know. If object is in scene you should call gameobject. if object is in project folder it called Prefab (Template of gameobject). If you want to know about MonoBehaviour Execution and Event [Try it](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for you effort and time, i will read the documentation you provided. Regards.